# Scrape HTML drop-down lists with Go?

Tags: go, web-scraping

I'm using the package `golang.org/x/net/html` to scrape data out of HTML pages and this has been working fine so far. However, I don't know how to extract data from a drop-down list like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select name="car" size="1" id="car">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>

<select name="animal" size="1" id="animal">
  <option value="dog">Dog</option>
  <option value="cat" selected>Cat</option>
  <option value="badger">Badger</option>
  <option value="mouse">Mouse</option>
</select>
```

I want to extract the pre-selected options, so the result becomes this:

```
car = audi
animal = cat
```

How can I accomplish this? In case `golang.org/x/net/html` is not capable of doing what I want, what else can I do to extract the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You absolutely can do it with "net/html":

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/html"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := "html"

    result := make(map[string]string)
    d := html.NewTokenizer(strings.NewReader(s))
    currID := ""
    for {
        tokenType := d.Next()
        if tokenType == html.ErrorToken {
            break
        }

        token := d.Token()
        switch tokenType {
        case html.StartTagToken:
            if token.Data == "select" {
                for _, a := range token.Attr {
                    if a.Key == "id" {
                        currID = a.Val
                    }
                }
            }
            if token.Data == "option" {
                isSelected := false
                for _, a := range token.Attr {
                    if a.Key == "selected" {
                        isSelected = true
                    }
                }
                if isSelected {
                    for _, a := range token.Attr {
                        if a.Key == "value" {
                            result[currID] = a.Val
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", result)
}
```

P.S. this code can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use [`gokogiri`](https://github.com/moovweb/gokogiri) for xpath selectors:

```
car, _ := doc.Search("//select[@id='car']/option[@selected]/text()")
animal, _ := doc.Search("//select[@id='animal']/option[@selected]/text()")
```